# join tables in sqlalchemy to get a many relationship in a query for a flask app

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

How do i query all of the manys-- 2 tables away from my groupby variable?

My data is structured like this (even though my database allows many-to-many everywhere)

my data is like a bowtie

**syntax** \......................................../ Whenz
 
**syntax** --**Clump**--**Clumpdetail** -- Whenz
**syntax** /..........................................\ Whenz

For each **syntax.filename** I want all of the **Whenz.freq**

**my model**

```
clump_syntaxs = db.Table('clump_syntaxs',
    db.Column('syntax_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('syntax.id')),
    db.Column('clump_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('clump.id')),
)

clump_deets = db.Table('clump_deets',
    db.Column('clumpdetail_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('clumpdetail.id')),
    db.Column('clump_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('clump.id')),
)
when_deets = db.Table('when_deets',
    db.Column('clumpdetail_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('clumpdetail.id')),
    db.Column('whenz_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('whenz.id')),
)
class Whenz(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    title = db.Column(db.String(150))
    freq = db.Column(db.String(150))
    frequency = db.relationship('Clumpdetail', secondary=when_deets,
        backref=db.backref('frequency', lazy='dynamic'))
    def __repr__(self):
        return  str(self.title)

class Clumpdetail(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    whenhour = db.Column(db.Time())
    wherevar = db.Column(db.String(150))
    cat = db.Column(db.String(150))
    clumps = db.relationship('Clump', secondary=clump_deets,
        backref=db.backref('deets', lazy='dynamic'))
    def __repr__(self):
        return str(self.cat)

class Clump(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    clumpname = db.Column(db.String(150), unique=True)
    ordervar = db.Column(db.Integer)
    syntaxs = db.relationship('Syntax', secondary=clump_syntaxs,
        backref=db.backref('clumps', lazy='dynamic'),order_by="Syntax.position",
                            collection_class=ordering_list('position'))
    def __repr__(self):
        return   str(self.clumpname)

class Syntax(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    filename = db.Column(db.String(150), unique=True,)
    jobs = db.relationship('Jobs',lazy='dynamic', backref='jobhistory')
    position = db.Column(db.Integer)
    def __repr__(self):
        return str(self.filename)
 .... cut.
```

**my attempt of many**

```
joblist=db.session.query((models.Syntax.filename).label('filename'),\
    (models.Clump.clumpname).label('clumpname'),\
    (models.Clumpdetail.whenhour).label('hour'),\
    (models.Clumpdetail.wherevar).label('where'),\
    (models.Clumpdetail.cat).label('cat'),\
    (models.Whenz.freq).label('freq'))\
.outerjoin((models.Syntax.clumps,models.Clump))\
.outerjoin((models.Clump.deets,models.Clumpdetail))\
.outerjoin((models.Clumpdetail.frequency,models.Whenz))\
.group_by(models.Syntax.filename).all()
```

I would expect this line

```
    (models.Whenz.freq).label('freq'))\
```

to give me all of the whenz, but it only gives me one.  Why is that?

I am able to get what i want using

```
models.Syntax.query.filter_by(filename=models.Syntax.query.first()\
.filename).first()\
.clumps.first()\
.deets.first()\
.frequency.all()
```

but this is just one by one, and i want it by syntax.filename

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because of the `group_by`. If you group by `syntax.filename`, you'll only have one row for each unique filename, so you won't get all of the `freq`s back.

If you want a SQLAlchemy core solution, remove the `group_by` and group the results yourself in python.

If you want a SQLAlchemy ORM solution, you can use `subqueryload`:

```
Syntax.query.options(subqueryload(Syntax.clumps).subqueryload(Clump.deets).subqueryload(Clumpdetail.frequency)).all()
```

Note: I believe you'll have to remove the `lazy="dynamic"` on `Syntax.clumps`, `Clump.deets`, and `Clumpdetail.frequency`.

Comment: Thank you! How do i connect the subquery to my query?  Not enough closing ')' should it be Syntax.query.options(subqueryload(Syntax.clumps).subqueryload(Clump.deets).subqueryload(Clumpdetail.frequency)).all() *note the extra ')' in ...ency)).all()

Comment: If i go the grouping in python, i've only ever done that with pandas, but it might slow down my app to use pandas just for that?  do you know a groupby method that will work for me that i can search examples?  seriously, thank you!  spending all day trying to figure this out

Comment: @ChetMeinzer Try it and find out. The rule of thumb is you shouldn't do premature optimizations. If you implement it and find out that part is slow, you can optimize it then; most likely some other part of your app will be the bottleneck, however.